# jQuery Star Rating Plugin is not recognizing {split:4}

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-plugins

I'm using the [jQuery Star Rating plugin](http://www.fyneworks.com/jquery/star-rating/) on an ASP.NET MVC site, and I can't get it to work with split stars. As best I can tell, I'm creating the proper radio buttons. I've tried using both the RadioButton helper method and pure HTML, and I've also tried with and without disabled inputs (on this particular page, I intend to use disabled). Here's what I've got on the page right now:

```
<input class="star {split:4}" type="radio" disabled="disabled" value="1" name="Rating"/>
...
<input class="star {split:4}" type="radio" disabled="disabled" value="19" name="Rating" checked="checked"/>
<input class="star {split:4}" type="radio" disabled="disabled" value="20" name="Rating"/>
```

When the page loads, it converts all the radio buttons to stars, but instead of 5 stars split into fourths, it shows 20 stars without splits. Any ideas what I'm missing?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Nevermind, I found the problem. I wasn't including jquery.MetaData.js, just the jquery.rating.js file. It's not listed as a required file on the download page, just as a related file, but the demos require it without mentioning it.

Comment: Oh man, documentation is so bad.. I've been looking for this solution second time.. fortunately I found your response in my votes history :) @Orkan you should do something about it..